# Apply SVG Filter to HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, canvas, svg, windows-runtime

**Objective:** Apply CSS Filters to video using html5 and JavaScript.

**Contraints:** The solution *must* be compatible with *Internet Exporer 10 (for Windows 8)*.  I am really making a Metro app.

**So Far:**
I have a `<video>` that I am pumping onto a `<canvas>`.  I thought I would be able to apply CSS filters directly to this (e.g. `invert` or `brightness`) but it turns out those are not compatible with IE10.

**Thoughts:** I am hoping for a way to apply SVG filters to the canvas.  Is this possible?  Do I need to copy the `<canvas>` to an `<image>` and apply the filters to that?  Alternatively, should there be a way to wrap the canvas in a `<foreignObject>`?

### Thank you for all your help!

Here is some code for those interested:

filters.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="1" height="1" version="1.1"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2 3" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

style.css:

```
.a {
    filter: url(filter.svg#blur);
    -ms-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

page.html:

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
            <canvas class="a" style="width: 180px;height:180px;margin-bottom: -5px;" data-win-bind="style.backgroundColor: bc; id: effectId" />
</div>
```

**The Following Code *Works*, albeit very slowly, to accomplish my goal. Thank you, Anthony!**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<svg id="svgroot"  viewbox="0 0 800 800" width="800" height="800"  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
    <defs>
<filter id="myHueRotate">
<feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" values="270"/>
</filter>
</defs>
<image id="a" filter="url(#myHueRotate)"  x="0" y="0" width="300" height="300" />
<image id="b" filter="url(#myHueRotate)"  x="300" y="0" width="300" height="300" />
<image id="c" filter="url(#myHueRotate)"  x="0" y="300" width="300" height="300" />
<image id="d" filter="url(#myHueRotate)"  x="300" y="300" width="300" height="300" />
</svg>
<canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
<video id="vid" src="movie.m4v" height="300" width="300" style="display: none" autoplay/>


<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'img.jpg';
  img.onload = function(){
    //ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    //var canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //var svgImage = document.getElementById('a');
    //svgImage.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", canvasImage);
    draw();
  }
img.load();

function draw(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid')
    ctx.drawImage(vid,0,0,300,300);
    var canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    document.getElementById('a').setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", canvasImage);
    document.getElementById('b').setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", canvasImage);
    document.getElementById('c').setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", canvasImage);
    document.getElementById('d').setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "xlink:href", canvasImage);
    setTimeout(draw,40);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of copying frames of `<canvas>` to `<image>` (which you *could* do via `toDataURL()`) I would suggest first trying to embed the canvas or video in the SVG directly via `<foreignObject>` and see if you can get filters to apply to that. But first: have you verified that IE10 supports the SVG filters you want at all, even on a static image?

Comment: Unfortunately IE9/10 does not support `<foreignObject>`

Comment: @RobertLongson - IE10 does support SVG filters being called via CSS though, so thereis hope. And IE9 as much it promised to be finally caught up, is now right there with IE7 and IE8, irrelevant unless your boss refuses to upgrade.  Read the Ma Bell quote I threw into my answer. Until we as developers stop worrying about IE users (which is hard, I know), they will always have us by the balls when it should obviously be the other way around 4 major alternative and better browsers later.

Comment: I wonder if Internet _Exporer_ was a deliberate slip? `;)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, articles to read:

[moving-to-standards-based-web-graphics-in-ie10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/12/07/moving-to-standards-based-web-graphics-in-ie10.aspx)

Notice specifically the sections:

> Use SVG, not VML

and

> Use CSS3, not DX Filters

In that second section, they mention:

> DX Filters are not the same as SVG Filter Effects, though both use the CSS property name filter.

Second article:

[Introduction to Filters and Transitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

They give a specific example of how to use `invert`, but, assuming it is *the* way in IE, I can see why it wasn't easy to find and may or may not work in your case. But the css would be:

```
#yourTargetElement {
     filter: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(invert=1);
}
```

They don't mention brightness, but they do mention several other filters and transitions, and that first article does mention using SVG. More details (hopefully helpful ones) at:

[SVG Filter Effects in IE10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10.aspx)

This looks like part 1 of the key:

> A filter is applied to an SVG element via the filter attribute, in the form of filter="url(#filterId)", or it can be applied as a CSS property filter:url(#filterId)

And this is part 2:

> There are 16 different filter primitives.

Now, I believe the 16 they refer to are the full set for SVG, but knowing MS, it could also mean either:

1. These are the 16 we support, or
2. These are the 16 we've invented so as to continue our claim to make IE standards-compliant and SVG/MathML friendly, but making it harder than it would be in any other browser...because we can.

Or, to quote Lily Tomlin: "We don't care, we don't have to...we're the phone company."

But, assuming MS is finally realizing they need to catch up, reading further on the 16 primitive filters, supposedly you just have your embedded SVG, with the filters in the right place (`defs`) and call them via css. Here is one of their examples (slightly modified and simplified by me):

#### HTML w/ Embedded SVG:

```
<div id="svg_wrapper">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" viewBox="0 0 800 533" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin">
    <defs>
     <filter id="filtersPicture">
             <feComposite operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" 
               in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" result="inputTo_6">
             </feComposite>      
             <feColorMatrix type="saturate" id="filter_6" values="2" 
                            data-filterId="6">
             </feColorMatrix>
             </filter>
   </svg>
  </div>
```

#### CSS (They use JS to make it dynamic, so beware):

```
<style type="text/css">
     #yourTargetElement{
             filter:url(#filtersPicture);
      }
 </style>
```

The reason I caution on how "easy" they make it look is because they are adding the style via js and an interactive form (maybe you have the same thing in mind), but I imagine that runs the same risk as calling an element in a script before it is in the DOM, in that it can't find the filter and throws an error. So be sure if you want to keep it simple (non-dynamic) and things still aren't working, to try putting the filter/svg above the style (even if this causes a flicker).

Comment: Thanks for the help Anthony!  I edited my question based on your response.  I esentially take a video, copy it to a canvas 25 times per second, copy the canvas to a data url, then set every image's src to that url.  (The SVG is then applied to the image).  Is there a better way to do that? It is very slow for even one video, and I was hoping to be able to do 9 videos simultaneously (asking a bit much, I know).  Is my approach basically what you recommend?

Comment: I honestly don't use IE ever since I moved to Linux/Mac. I'd probably still use it for testing if it was an option, but blissfully it is not.  So you're saying that you are applying the svg filter to each image as it loads, and you're not sure if that's why it's slow, or are you wondering if you're roll-you're-on method of rendering the video frame-by-frame is the bottleneck? I'd inclined to go with the latter, as I can only imagine that getting the data url for each frame is memory murder.  I didn't even know that was an option with canvas. Are you using the base64 data URL or the temp url?

Comment: That last question was based on the assumption that IE/JS handles generating a base64 data URL similar to the HTML5 File API, which offers both the full data URL (which is huge and could slow things down just outputting it) and a temp url (which is a short local url that essentially points to where the data is being cached). The latter is also faster because it doesn't have to pre-load and read the entire file to generate the base64. Not sure if this is an option via the canvas technique you're using, but the keywords to dig deeper is "object URL" vs "Data URL" (the latter being the base64).